# Delete user record from database with a button

Tags: php, html

I am creating an admin site and all the users are on it. I want to make a delete button on each user row, so when I click that, the user will be removed from the database.

```
<?php
    $hey = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, email, rr, house, date, bil, rank FROM user");
    $hey->execute();
    $hey ->bind_result($id, $username, $email, $rr, $house, $date, $bil, $rank);

    echo 
        "<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' style='background-color: white; margin-left: -4px;' border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>BRUGERNAVN</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
        <th>PENGE</th>
        <th>HUS</th>
        <th>RANK</th>
        <th>BIL</th>
        <th>DATO</th>
        <th>Indstillinger</th>
        </tr>";

        while( $hey->fetch() ){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $id ."</td> ". "<td>" .$username ."</td> ". "<td>" .$email ."</td> ". "<td>" .$rr ."</td>". "<td>". $house . "</td>". "<td>". $rank . "</td>". "<td>". $bil . "</td>". "<td>". $date . "</td>". "<td> <center>DELETE</center> </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

    $hey->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need first HTML checkbox for each user line, then a form to send and a page/url dedicated to work on deletions.

You should use functions to fetch/display/delete your datas, as putting everything in the same file like you do is, for many things, a bad idea.

Have a look at MVC development, and the PHP PIP minimalist framework that will help you understand this principle.

But, if you just want a delete on the display, you must use JavaScript.